# Доступ к объекту ArrayList Java

Tags: java, объекты, get, arraylist, getter

Создал `ArrayList`, через цикл добавил в него 5 элементов класса, которые имеют приватные переменные, доступ к которым через `get`. Если просто создавать элемент класса, то пишем `ИмяЕлемента.getId();`
Как быть с `ArrayList`?

Answer (score 1):

Доступ к элементам списка осуществляется через метод get(n), где n - индекс элемента, который нужно получить.

```
ArrayList<MyObject> list = new ArrayList();
list.add(new MyObject(0));
list.get(0).getId();

class MyObject {
    private int id;

    MyObject(int id) {
        this.id = id
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }
}
```

Comment: ArrayList list=new ArrayList();
list.add(new МойОбъект();
list.get(индекс).getId(); 
не работает

Comment: @DALVROT обновил ответ. Возможно вы не указали тип элементов списка <МойОбъект>

Comment: огромное спасибо! Не разобрался сначала. Самая глупая ошибка...

Comment: @DALVROT Смените ArrayList<MyObject> list на интерфейс List<MyObject> list, на тот случай если вам придется поменять реализацию интерфейса List.